# I want to change the order of some views dynamically in Android

Tags: android

Image : https://www.dropbox.com/s/prmw3vb6pugrefy/Untitled.png?dl=0

Please visit above link or [Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prmw3vb6pugrefy/Untitled.png?dl=0) to see whole question in an image.
i am not able to add image here due to less reputation.

In this given image there is two views is present

1 : VideoView for Media

2 : FrameLayout for SurfaceView Camera

Working Proper :
On activity startup Video(VideoView for media) is playing on screen properly and front camera(FrameLayout for camera) is also using on top-right corner with in a VideoView
i.e. FrameLayout within VideoView (On Top-Right Corner of VideoView)

If we click "Button" then frameLayout getting bigger and videoview getting small and vice versa.
i.e. now VideoView with in FrameLayout (On Top-Right Corner of FrameLayout)

**Issue :** if click on Button all functionality working fine i.e. VideoView getting small and FrameLayout getting bigger but in case of vise versa VideoView getting bigger and FrameLayout getting small but now camera view is not visible. Actually it is in background of VideoView..and here i am not able to make it visible. or bring FrameLayout on top of VideoView.

Here i have used all possible solutions but not able to resolved this issue.

So anybody can help to make it visible ?

I have also attached code for this please help.

.java file

```
mVideoView11 = (VideoView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.videoview11);
myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.id.frame_video_camera);



    public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == button2){
                changeLayout();
            }else if(v == button3){
                changeLayoutAgain();
            }
    }

// for large Camera view(FrameLayout)
    public void changeLayout(){

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mVideoView11.getLayoutParams();
                head_params1.setMargins(400, 20, 10, 0);
                head_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                head_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


                head_params1.height=360;
                head_params1.width=200;

                mVideoView11.setLayoutParams(head_params1);
                head_params1 = null;

                // Camera view

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myCameraPreview.getLayoutParams();
                head_params.setMargins(0, 250, 0, 5);
                head_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                head_params.width=500;
                head_params.width = head_params.FILL_PARENT;


                myCameraPreview.setLayoutParams(head_params);
                head_params = null;

            }



    // For large VideoView

        public void changeLayoutAgain(){

                // for large video view
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mVideoView11.getLayoutParams();
                head_params1.setMargins(0, 250, 0, 5);
                head_params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                head_params1.height=500;
                head_params1.width = head_params1.FILL_PARENT;

                mVideoView11.setLayoutParams(head_params1);
                head_params1 = null;

                // Camera view
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myCameraPreview.getLayoutParams();
                //head_params.setMargins(500, 20, 5, 5);
                head_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                head_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                head_params.height=200;
                head_params.width=200;

                myCameraPreview.setLayoutParams(head_params);
                head_params = null;

            }
```

.xml file

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_video_camera"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </FrameLayout>
```